# YII2 Rich Text Editors

Tags: yii2, rte

1) Which of the **rich text editors** do you use for **YII2**? And why?

2) Is there any solution (extension) for the **responsivity** to specify different layouts for the same text  block  for mobile and desktop (as in Elementor or Visual Composer in Wordpress)?

Comment: Opinion based question is off-topic .

Comment: I've reformulated the question.

Answer (score 1):

**1)**
I personally always use [TinyMce](http://www.tinymce.com/) [plugin from 2amigos](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget) .

TinyMce is powerful enough in its free version to fill all your needs and checks, and if something is lacking its simple and well documented so extending the component funcionality as per your wishes its very easy.

**2)** You could extend all your tags and blocks in tinymce to implement custom classes that make them responsive or hidden in certain resolutions based on your media queries. So yes. You could.